# Set Wallpaper by system wallpaper manager

Tags: java, android

I have a wallpaper app.
All the wallpapers are set by using `WallpaperManager.setBitmap()`.

How to query the system default wallpaper chooser, and then set the choosen  wallpaper?

Comment: Found answer here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21348052/how-to-send-images-to-gallery-for-setting-the-wallpaper

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER">
```

add this permission

and

```
WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
try {
    myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.five);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: this metod im using now, but i want set wallpapers using default manager in ROM. So user can change position and other.